# Type ??? has no member

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and am trying to follow the Stanford Uni course CS193P.
I did originally type the code in but got multiple errors, so as I could not find a soluion on the forums, I copied the code in from the Democode provided.
Now I get errors, but not the same as before.
Here is the file that has the errors:

```
//
//ViewController.swift
//  FaceIt
//
//  Created by CS193p Instructor.
//  Copyright © 2017 Stanford University. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var expression = FacialExpression(eyes: .closed, mouth: .frown) {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    private func updateUI()
    {
        switch expression.eyes {
        case .open:
            FaceView?.eyesOpen = true
        case .closed:
            FaceView?.eyesOpen = false
        case .squinting:
            FaceView?.eyesOpen = false
        }
        FaceView?.mouthCurvature = mouthCurvatures[expression.mouth] ?? 0.0
    }
    private let mouthCurvatures =
        [FacialExpression.Mouth.grin:0.5,.frown:-1.0,.smile:1.0,.neutral:0.0,.smirk:-0.5]
}
```

I can't understand why it says "Type 'FaceView?'has no member 'eyesOpen' 
as in the file FaceView it contains the code:

```
class FaceView: UIView
    {
        // Public API
        // 1.0 is full smile and -1.0 is full frown
        @IBInspectable
        var mouthCurvature: Double = 0.5 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
        @IBInspectable
        var eyesOpen: Bool = true { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
        @IBInspectable
        var scale: CGFloat = 0.9 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
        @IBInspectable
        var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
        @IBInspectable
        var color: UIColor = UIColor.blue { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
        func changeScale(byReactingTo pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
        {
```

I also get the same type of error for 'mouthCurvature'.
The only doubt I have is the type of file that I set up FacialExpression, as in the lecture the lecturer dragged it inform somewhere.  I set it up as a Cocoa Touch file. Is this why I get the error?
Otherwise can anybody explain why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `eyesOpen` property is an instance property—it exists on an instance of the `FaceView` type, not on the `FaceView` type itself. You should probably declare a property of type `FaceView?`, and then refer to that instead of the class name (the time to use the class name is when you are accessing a member that is declared `class var`/`let`/`func` or `static var`/`let`/`func`, and thus belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific instance of the type). So, do something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var faceView: FaceView?

    // add some code somewhere, maybe in viewDidLoad, to assign something to faceView

    private func updateUI() {
        switch self.expression.eyes {
    case .open:
        self.faceView?.eyesOpen = true
    // ... etc ...
    }
}
```